# PHP function to create charts from strings of encoded values not separated

Tags: php, sql, split, decode, utf

I have a difficult one :-)

In a specific column of a database there are strings of encoded values without separator and I'm trying to convert them back to the original comma separated numeric values

These are 2 (simplified) examples of encoded strings (the real ones have 50 figures each):

```
â‚¬â€šÆ’
â€žâ€¦â€
```

They have been encoded according to the following "map"

```
0   =   '€'   =   'â‚¬'
2   =   '‚'   =   'â€š'
3   =   'ƒ'   =   'Æ’'
4   =   '„'   =   'â€ž'
5   =   '…'   =   'â€¦'
6   =   '†'   =   'â€'
```

etc...

I'm trying to convert them back to the equivalent comma separated numeric values:

```
0,2,3
4,5,6
```

These are some of the real strings

```
â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬Ã—Ã—Ã—Ã“Ã“ÃŸÃŸÃ‘Ã‘Ã©Ã©Ã©ÃšÃ©Ã©Ã©Ã©ÃŸÃ´Ã´Ã´Ã¬ÃµÃµÃ¬ÃµÃµÃµÃ®Ã¿Ã¿Ã¿Ã³ÃºÃºÃºÃ»Ã»Ã»Ã«
â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬ÂÂÂ¡Â¡Â¡Â¡Å¸Â¦Â¦Â¦Â¦ÂºÂºÂºÃšÃšÃ’Ã’ÃŸÃŸÃ‹Ã›Ã›Ã Ã Ã”Ã´Ã¿Ã‡Â¦
â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬â‚¬Ã¿Ã¿Ã—Ã—ÂºÃ‡Ã‡Ã‡Ã„ÃŒÃŒÂ¾ÂµÂ½Â½Â½Â·ÃƒÃƒÃƒÂ¼Â¾Â¾Â¾Â¨Â¤Â¤Â¤Å¾Å¾Å¾Å¾Å¾
```

I made an array with the "map" that should help to decode them

```
$flowGraphMap =
[
    [   'â‚¬'   ,   '€' ,   0   ]   ,
    [   ' '     ,   ' ' ,   1   ]   ,
    [   'â€š'   ,   '‚' ,   2   ]   ,
    [   'Æ’'    ,   'ƒ' ,   3   ]   ,
    [   'â€ž'   ,   '„' ,   4   ]   ,
    [   'â€¦'   ,   '…' ,   5   ]   ,
    [   'â€'    ,   '†' ,   6   ]   ,
    [   'â€¡'   ,   '‡' ,   7   ]   ,
    [   'Ë†'    ,   'ˆ' ,   8   ]   ,
    [   'â€°'   ,   '‰' ,   9   ]   ,
    [   'Å'     ,   'Š' ,   10  ]   ,
    [   'â€¹'   ,   '‹' ,   11  ]   ,
    [   'Å’'    ,   'Œ' ,   12  ]   ,
    [   ' '     ,   ' ' ,   13  ]   ,
    [   'Å½'    ,   'Ž' ,   14  ]   ,
    [   ' '     ,   ' ' ,   15  ]   ,
    [   ' '     ,   ' ' ,   16  ]   ,
    [   'â€˜'   ,   '‘' ,   17  ]   ,
    [   'â€™'   ,   '’' ,   18  ]   ,
    [   'â€œ'   ,   '“' ,   19  ]   ,
    [   'â€'    ,   '”' ,   20  ]   ,
    [   'â€¢'   ,   '•' ,   21  ]   ,
    [   'â€“'   ,   '–' ,   22  ]   ,
    [   'â€”'   ,   '—' ,   23  ]   ,
    [   'Ëœ'    ,   '˜' ,   24  ]   ,
    [   'â„¢'   ,   '™' ,   25  ]   ,
    [   'Å¡'    ,   'š' ,   26  ]   ,
    [   'â€º'   ,   '›' ,   27  ]   ,
    [   'Å“'    ,   'œ' ,   28  ]   ,
    [   ' '     ,   ' ' ,   29  ]   ,
    [   'Å¾'    ,   'ž' ,   30  ]   ,
    [   'Å¸'    ,   'Ÿ' ,   31  ]   ,
    [   'Â'     ,   ' ' ,   32  ]   ,
    [   'Â¡'    ,   '¡' ,   33  ]   ,
    [   'Â¢'    ,   '¢' ,   34  ]   ,
    [   'Â£'    ,   '£' ,   35  ]   ,
    [   'Â¤'    ,   '¤' ,   36  ]   ,
    [   'Â¥'    ,   '¥' ,   37  ]   ,
    [   'Â¦'    ,   '¦' ,   38  ]   ,
    [   'Â§'    ,   '§' ,   39  ]   ,
    [   'Â¨'    ,   '¨' ,   40  ]   ,
    [   'Â©'    ,   '©' ,   41  ]   ,
    [   'Âª'    ,   'ª' ,   42  ]   ,
    [   'Â«'    ,   '«' ,   43  ]   ,
    [   'Â¬'    ,   '¬' ,   44  ]   ,
    [   'Â¬'    ,   '¬' ,   45  ]   ,
    [   'Â®'    ,   '®' ,   46  ]   ,
    [   'Â¯'    ,   '¯' ,   47  ]   ,
    [   'Â°'    ,   '°' ,   48  ]   ,
    [   'Â±'    ,   '±' ,   49  ]   ,
    [   'Â²'    ,   '²' ,   50  ]   ,
    [   'Â³'    ,   '³' ,   51  ]   ,
    [   'Â´'    ,   '´' ,   52  ]   ,
    [   'Âµ'    ,   'µ' ,   53  ]   ,
    [   'Â¶'    ,   '¶' ,   54  ]   ,
    [   'Â·'    ,   '·' ,   55  ]   ,
    [   'Â¸'    ,   '¸' ,   56  ]   ,
    [   'Â¹'    ,   '¹' ,   57  ]   ,
    [   'Âº'    ,   'º' ,   58  ]   ,
    [   'Â»'    ,   '»' ,   59  ]   ,
    [   'Â¼'    ,   '¼' ,   60  ]   ,
    [   'Â½'    ,   '½' ,   61  ]   ,
    [   'Â¾'    ,   '¾' ,   62  ]   ,
    [   'Â¿'    ,   '¿' ,   63  ]   ,
    [   'Ã€'    ,   'À' ,   64  ]   ,
    [   'Ã'     ,   'Á' ,   65  ]   ,
    [   'Ã‚'    ,   'Â' ,   66  ]   ,
    [   'Ãƒ'    ,   'Ã' ,   67  ]   ,
    [   'Ã„'    ,   'Ä' ,   68  ]   ,
    [   'Ã…'    ,   'Å' ,   69  ]   ,
    [   'Ã†'    ,   'Æ' ,   70  ]   ,
    [   'Ã‡'    ,   'Ç' ,   71  ]   ,
    [   'Ãˆ'    ,   'È' ,   72  ]   ,
    [   'Ã‰'    ,   'É' ,   73  ]   ,
    [   'ÃŠ'    ,   'Ê' ,   74  ]   ,
    [   'Ã‹'    ,   'Ë' ,   75  ]   ,
    [   'ÃŒ'    ,   'Ì' ,   76  ]   ,
    [   'Ã'     ,   'Í' ,   77  ]   ,
    [   'ÃŽ'    ,   'Î' ,   78  ]   ,
    [   'Ã'     ,   'Ï' ,   79  ]   ,
    [   'Ã'     ,   'Ð' ,   80  ]   ,
    [   'Ã‘'    ,   'Ñ' ,   81  ]   ,
    [   'Ã’'    ,   'Ò' ,   82  ]   ,
    [   'Ã“'    ,   'Ó' ,   83  ]   ,
    [   'Ã”'    ,   'Ô' ,   84  ]   ,
    [   'Ã•'    ,   'Õ' ,   85  ]   ,
    [   'Ã–'    ,   'Ö' ,   86  ]   ,
    [   'Ã—'    ,   '×' ,   87  ]   ,
    [   'Ã˜'        ,   'Ø' ,   88  ]   ,
    [   'Ã™'    ,   'Ù' ,   89  ]   ,
    [   'Ãš'    ,   'Ú' ,   90  ]   ,
    [   'Ã›'    ,   'Û' ,   91  ]   ,
    [   'Ãœ'    ,   'Ü' ,   92  ]   ,
    [   'Ã'     ,   'Ý' ,   93  ]   ,
    [   'Ãž'    ,   'Þ' ,   94  ]   ,
    [   'ÃŸ'    ,   'ß' ,   95  ]   ,
    [   'Ã'     ,   'à' ,   96  ]   ,
    [   'Ã¡'    ,   'á' ,   97  ]   ,
    [   'Ã¢'    ,   'â' ,   98  ]   ,
    [   'Ã£'    ,   'ã' ,   99  ]   ,
    [   'Ã¤'    ,   'ä' ,   100 ]   ,
    [   'Ã¥'    ,   'å' ,   101 ]   ,
    [   'Ã¦'    ,   'æ' ,   102 ]   ,
    [   'Ã§'    ,   'ç' ,   103 ]   ,
    [   'Ã¨'    ,   'è' ,   104 ]   ,
    [   'Ã©'    ,   'é' ,   105 ]   ,
    [   'Ãª'    ,   'ê' ,   106 ]   ,
    [   'Ã«'    ,   'ë' ,   107 ]   ,
    [   'Ã¬'    ,   'ì' ,   108 ]   ,
    [   'Ã¬'    ,   'í' ,   109 ]   ,
    [   'Ã®'    ,   'î' ,   110 ]   ,
    [   'Ã¯'    ,   'ï' ,   111 ]   ,
    [   'Ã°'    ,   'ð' ,   112 ]   ,
    [   'Ã±'    ,   'ñ' ,   113 ]   ,
    [   'Ã²'    ,   'ò' ,   114 ]   ,
    [   'Ã³'    ,   'ó' ,   115 ]   ,
    [   'Ã´'    ,   'ô' ,   116 ]   ,
    [   'Ãµ'    ,   'õ' ,   117 ]   ,
    [   'Ã¶'    ,   'ö' ,   118 ]   ,
    [   'Ã·'    ,   '÷' ,   119 ]   ,
    [   'Ã¸'    ,   'ø' ,   120 ]   ,
    [   'Ã¹'    ,   'ù' ,   121 ]   ,
    [   'Ãº'    ,   'ú' ,   122 ]   ,
    [   'Ã»'    ,   'û' ,   123 ]   ,
    [   'Ã¼'    ,   'ü' ,   124 ]   ,
    [   'Ã½'    ,   'ý' ,   125 ]   ,
    [   'Ã¾'    ,   'þ' ,   126 ]   ,
    [   'Ã¿'    ,   'ÿ' ,   127 ]   ,
];
```

This PHP function should fetch these strings from the SQL table, separate the encoded values, transform them in the correspondent numeric values and create one scatter chart for each record.

Thanks to All!!

Comment: So you basically want to decode your string based on your $flowGraphMap? Did you do any attempt to do so?

Comment: How do you know if you should check for â€ (number 6) or â€s (number 2)? I What is the reason you are doing this in the first place?

Comment: They come from a sensor that measures the intensity of a liquid fluid flowing through a pipe. It stores the values in a string of 50x ASCII-128 values (those in the 2nd column of the array) that correspond to numeric values (those in the 3rd column). The sensor then exports the string into a CSV file and in that moment it encodes them as displayed in the 1st column of the array. I should probably decode them back to ASCII when I import the CSV file to my SQL database, to obtain a "simple" string of 50 ASCII characters that I could separate with a function like str_split() or similar...